# Structure sheaf of cyclic coverings

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Lazarsfeld's *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry, I* Proposition 4.1.6 is the following statement:

> Let $X$ be a variety, and $L$ a line bundle on $X$. Suppose given an
>   integer $m \geq 1$ plus a non-zero section $s \in \Gamma(X, L^{\otimes m})$
>   which defines a divisor $D \subseteq X$. Then there exists a
>   finite flat covering $\pi \colon Y \to X$ (branched along $D$), where $Y$ is a scheme
>   having the property that the pull-back $L' = \pi^* L$ of $L$ carries a
>   section $s' \in \Gamma(Y, L')$ with $(s')^m = \pi^* s$.

The proof of this claim in the affine case essentially amounts to defining
\begin{equation}
Y = \{ t^m = s \} \subseteq X \times \mathbb A^1 \xrightarrow{\mathrm{pr}_1} X.
\end{equation}

Then, the following Remark 4.1.7 states that:

> It follows from the construction that there is a canonical isomorphism
>   \begin{equation}\pi_* \mathcal O_Y = \mathcal O_X \oplus L^{\otimes -1} \oplus \cdots \oplus L^{\otimes (1-m)}.\end{equation}

How can I check this remark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flat covering $Y$ is the closed subvariety in the total space of $L$ that is in $T=\text{Tot} L = \underline{\operatorname{Spec}}(\operatorname{Sym} L^*)$, given by the ideal sheaf generated by $(s')^m - \pi^* s$ . This symmetric algebra of the line bundle is just $\operatorname{Sym} L^* = \bigoplus_{i \geq 0} L^{-i}$, and 
$$
p_* \mathcal{O}_T = \bigoplus_{i \geq 0} L^{-i},
$$
here $p$ is the canonical projection $p: T \to X$, and $\pi = p|_Y$. So, if $U \subset X$ is an open affine set functions over $p^{-1}(U)$ are polynomials in $s'$ with coefficients being pullbacks of functions on $U$. The ring of functions on $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is the quotient of this polynomial algebra by the ideal generated by  $(s')^m - \pi^* s$. Therefore,
$$
\pi_* \mathcal O_Y = \mathcal O_X \oplus L^{\otimes -1} \oplus \cdots \oplus L^{\otimes (1-m)}.
$$